# Can new account be merged with old (deleted) account?

Tags: support

I suppose my old account has been deleted, as it is grayed out now. It is user862. Or, is it possible to still merge that account with my new account? Just curious. Never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been informed by those with more knowledge than I that deleted accounts can not be undeleted unless the deletion was somehow a mistake on the part of Stack Exchange. If you would like to confirm this with someone who works for SE and/or suggest that the deletion was in fact their mistake, I suggest you use the "contact" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It seems, then, that the policy is "we won't" rather than "we can't." The weird thing about it is I still have some questions/answers from my old account on this account. It's as if there was an incomplete merger when I created this [new] account from the same e-mail. Thank you again for investigating.